# Precalc - Trig Identities

Tags: trigonometry

I only need a hint as to where to go from here. My problem is this:

$$ \dfrac{1+\tan(x)}{\sin(x)}-\sec(x) $$

Here's my work trying to solve the problem, up until I got stuck. Did I make a mistake somewhere or make it more complicated than it should have been?

$$ \dfrac{(1+\tan(x))(\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}-\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)\sin(x)}=\dfrac{(1+\tan(x))(\cos(x))-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)\sin(x)}=\dfrac{1+\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{{\sin(x)}}=\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}+\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{\sin(x)}-\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}=\csc(x)+\sec(x)-1 $$

Comment: You neglected $\cos(x)$ in the second line.  You didn't multiply $1 + \tan(x)$ by $\cos(x)$

Comment: Same technique as your other problems: write everything in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ (which means you should get rid of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ and so on). Gather together fractions over a common denominator. Simplify. Use $\sin^x + \cos^2x = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you neglected $\cos(x)$ after combining the fractional expressions altogether.  So from the end of the first line,

$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{(1 + \tan(x))\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} &= \dfrac{\cos(x) + \tan(x)\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\\
&= \dfrac{\cos(x) + \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\cdot \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\\
&= \dfrac{\cos(x) + \sin(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\\
&= \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}\\
&= \csc(x)
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $ c = \cos(x)$ and $s = \sin(x)$. Then the expression you gave is
$$
\frac{1 + s/c}{s} - \frac{1}{c}  \\
= \frac{c+s}{cs} - \frac{1}{c} \\
= \frac{c+s}{cs} - \frac{s}{cs} \\
= \frac{c+s-s}{cs} \\
= \frac{c}{cs} \\
= \frac{1}{s} \\
= \text{cosec}(x)
$$
This same technique will work with all your other similar problems. The only thing you need to know is that $c^2 + s^2 = 1$.